# why appcompat-v7 can`t use compileOnly In library module

Tags: android, gradle

we know gradle 3.x.x update the dependency configuration, I have a question when use, we know If the project use v7:26.0.1, It's better to use same version in library module, so I think use **compileOnly** is the best choice, it will pass the compile time and use app library's v7 code at runtime, it will reduce apk size  and don`t care the v7 version right?
but it you try , you will find it can't pass compile time, why?

These are the errors I'm getting, and they are all related to xml not finding values.

```
Error:(43) No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package 'com.yalantis.ucrop.test'

Error:(19, 20) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title').
```

Comment: Please, add your build.gradle, at least its part with dependencies

Comment: It almost clearly, anyway , this is code fragment in build.gradle :    compileOnly 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

Answer (score 1):

`compileOnly` means it is only compiled. Meaning at runtime, when it needs the AppCompat library, it isn't present because the library isn't added to the APK itself.

You can do `compileOnly` with libraries like Lombok because it isn't needed at runtime - only compile time. AppCompat though, is needed at runtime as well. Don't use `compileOnly` with it. Use `implementation` (or `compile` if you have a gradle version that uses that).

You could use the `compileOnly` keyword with e.g. an annotation library (like Lombok) because the references to the libraries are usually removed at compile time (and converted to non-library code). There are of course exceptions, but that's an example of usage.

<sub>The APK is smaller with `compileOnly` because the library isn't added to the APK. You can't use any library features at runtime when you use `compileOnly` because, at runtime, the library can't be found</sub>

Comment: "it isn't present because the library isn't added to the APK itself." I know that, but the main module will provide the v7 AppCompat dependence

Comment: @zpy any external modules also need to declare the dependencies

Comment: I want make apk size smaller, declare repeat will make different version code all in apk.